# vlf-mode, delete up to end of file

Tags: deletion, large-files

I am viewing a large file (512 MB) with `vlf-mode`. How can I delete from a point of the file to the end?

The standard approach of selecting the text from a point to the end and then deleting it does not work. 
In fact, the file is subdivided in many sub buffers, 512 in my case, and so I am not able to extend the selection between these sub buffers.

UPDATE: Actually, if I try to delete a single character and then I save the file, nothing will be saved! So I have got even a bigger problem

Comment: Your question doesn't seem too clear, particularly given the last paragraph. Try to provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: Ok I will do it, I am trying to figuring out how to enable vlf when launching emacs with `emacs -Q`, it is listed as installed but I can't use it